# LyX: Add contents line with specific line number in ERT

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I am attaching two .pdf documents to my main document, which is written in LyX. I would like that the titles of them appeared at the end of the table of contents.

So far, I've been successful in adding them by inserting with ERT

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Additional document 1}
```

and changing the page count using e.g.

```
\setcounter{page}{150}
```

However, if I want to add two attachments:

```
\setcounter{page}{104}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Additional doc 1}
\setcounter{page}{154}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Additional doc 2}
```

Then both of them are listed as page 154 in the TOC.

It should be noted that I am using [this](http://www.aarondefazio.com/tangentially/?p=19) template, and adding the ERT under the Appendix box in the main lyx file.

[image]

Which compiles fine (but does not have the correct page numbers)

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: This can't work. `\addcontentsline` is "executed" at shipout time, at the end of the page. How are you attaching the pdf? With \includepdf`?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer. I was planning on just manually attaching it using preview. Hence the need for manual control of page numbers. I am using [this](http://www.aarondefazio.com/tangentially/?p=19) template and adding the above lines under the Appendix. It works, but, as said, the page numbers are identical.

Comment: The commands must be on different pages. So you need something like `\newpage \mbox{} <your code> ` for each of them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\addcontentsline` is "executed" at shipout time when a page is written to the pdf. If you want them to refer to different pages the commands must be on different pages too. So one way to do it is to use

```
      \newpage \mbox{} <your code>
```

for each of them.

Another possibility which produce less empty pages is this here. The additional code musst be at the end of document. If you are using packages which needs an unrobust \thepage at the end of the document like lastpage it will break them (but lastpage doesn't make much sense in your setup anyway).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{abc}

\newpage\section{cde}

\newpage % newpage before making thepage robust!!
\mbox{}  % force a shipout 
\robustify{\thepage} % avoid that \thepage expands directly
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\thepage{123}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Additional document 1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\thepage{134}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Additional document 2}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\thepage{127}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Additional document 3}

\end{document}
```